# Ask the user what operation to do in every file in a directory in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I have to write a bash script that should list all files in the home directory of a specific user and for each file ask the user an input to decide if it should be removed or compressed.

I should use `ls -l` to list the file.
I thought to use `xarg -l` to execute a command for each entry but I'm not sure on how to make it work with the user input part.

Comment: Do NOT [parse the output of ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls). To get help here, tell us what you have tried so far. What's your sample code? Where are you stuck?

Comment: show yours code you have already created